# Antivirus (Symantec) is re-quarantining files in the quarantine folder

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, symantec

Since yesterday I am getting constant notifications of threats Symantec is finding, except they are all in the quarantine folder. They are then "moved" to the quarantine folder, and then again I get notifications about the same threats. Is it safe to delete my quarantine folder? Moreover, is something seriously wrong with my machine?

Using Windows 7 SP1, Symantec Endpoint Protection 12.1.2015.2015.105

[image]

Comment: Only **you**, the user of **your system**, can decide if you want to empty the quarantine folder.  As to the reason SEP was detecting files in the quarantine file, the simplest explaination,  is the files were still in memory and/or attempting to infect again.  So they were being detected, by a different module of SEP, which is a good thing.

Comment: Try to check if you don't have two antivirus instances fighting together.